# Bind text to selected item in combobox

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding, combobox

I have a text field on the database, but now I don't want it to be a free open field, I want to restrict it to: let's say A, B and C.

For this I want to use a Combobox.

Question: How do I bind the selected item to the string property, given that the Items of the combobox are defined in XAML?

XAML:

```
 <ComboBox SelectedValue="{Binding Path=MyProperty}"> <!-- Not working-->
   <ComboBoxItem>A</ComboBoxItem>
   <ComboBoxItem>B</ComboBoxItem>
   <ComboBoxItem>C</ComboBoxItem>
 </ComboBox>
```

Class:

```
public Class MyClass:INotifyPropertyChanged
{
private string myProperty;
public string MyProperty
{
 get{return myProperty;}
 set{
      myProperty=value;
      OnPropertyChanged("MyProperty");
    }
 }
}
```

So, the user will change the selected item, and the new value will be updated on the databound object.

EDIT:
Thanks to the comments and answers I partially solved the problem, the only issue was that the combobox selection was empty when the program started. I solved it like this:

```
<ComboBox SelectedValuePath="Content">
 <ComboBoxItem>A</ComboBoxItem>
 <ComboBoxItem>B</ComboBoxItem>
 <ComboBoxItem>C</ComboBoxItem>
  <ComboBox.SelectedValue>
   <Binding Path="MyProperty" Mode="TwoWay"/>
  </ComboBox.SelectedValue>
 </ComboBox>
```

I moved the selected value part out of the attributes of the Combobox, and used property element sintax, this ensures that the collection is defined before it is used.

Comment: Try to set the BindingMode in TwoWay in your XAML

Comment: Yes, that works, but I get System.Windows.Controls.ComboBoxItem: B saved on the object.

Comment: Also, I don't get the original value displayed as the selected comboboxitem on the combobox when the application starts.

Comment: Then you may switch the BindingMode to OneWayToSource

Comment: That works too, but there's no selected value.

Comment: Can you be more precise ?

Comment: When the application starts, I expect to see a "B" selected on the Combobox because that is the value retrieved from the database, but the selection is empty, How ever, if I expand the combobox , select "C" and save the changes, I do get a "C" saved correctly to the database.

Comment: Then keep the binding in TwoWay and set the property MyProperty with the value from the database when you load the page.

Comment: That sounds good, but I'm using Entity Framework, wouldn't that cause the State of the entity to change to "Modified"? now, this normally wouldn't be a problem, but when the user saves changes, I retrieve all entities with entityState==modified and do some stuff to them, If I can't find a XAML solution for this, I will solve it this way for sure.

Comment: Never used Entity Framework so I can't really answer this question, sorry.

Comment: You have been really helpful, Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The Wpf `ComboBox` has three selection properties and one display property:

- `SelectedItem`
- `SelectedValue`
- `SelectedValuePath`
- `DisplayMemberPath`

When using `SelectedValue` you should also set the `SelectedValuePath` (almost always). Understand that the `Items` in your case contains a sequence (`ItemCollection`) of `ComboBoxItem` objects, and just like any other object you must specify the `SelectedValuePath` (read property) that you want to bind to; In this case, you want to access the `ComboBoxItem.Content` property ([http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.contentcontrol.content(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.contentcontrol.content%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)).

```
<ComboBox SelectedValue="{Binding Path=MyProperty}" SelectedValuePath="Content">
  <ComboBoxItem>A</ComboBoxItem>
  <ComboBoxItem>B</ComboBoxItem>
  <ComboBoxItem>C</ComboBoxItem>
</ComboBox>
```

Now you are binding the `SelctedValue` to the `MyProperty` property using the selected item's `Content` property, which happens to be the strings you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks, you guys are good. I got the value saved correctly on the object, but but there's no selected value on the combobox when the application starts.

Answer (score 0):

I don't like hard coding combobox items. In this situation being so simple I'd have a list of that type to the itemsource of the combo box. If it's more complicated than an List of strings, I'd make a lookup table in your database and use that instead. For the String list route it would be something like:

```
    public List<String> LetterTypes { get; set; }
    public String SelectedLetterType { get; set; }
```

int ctor:

```
    LetterTypes = new List<String> { A, B, C }
```

Then in your View:

```
    <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding LetterTypes}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedLetterType}" />
```

I see you already found a fix for your problem but maybe for future reference, this may be another way to populate a combobox.