# populate a combobox using another combobox selected item, in WPF

Tags: c#, mysql, wpf, combobox

I know this may have been asked and answered before. But I couldn't use them in my problem since i'm new to wpf and connecting database in c#.

this is the problem : I have a mysql database and its table has 2 columns country and district. I'm selecting country from a combo box which is fine. and I want to select district according to the country. I'm using 2 comboboxes for selecting Country and District.

Still I cannot load district when I selected a country.I think my sql string and wpf event handling might throw the problem.

```
         string new_student_sql = "SELECT Id,Name FROM world.city WHERE 
         CountryCode = '"; 

         string connectionStr = new_student_sql + comboBoxCountry.Text + 
         "' AND District= '" + comboBoxDistrict.Text + "'";


         MySqlCommand newStudent = new MySqlCommand(connectionStr, conn);
         newStudent.CommandText = connectionStr;
         conn.Open();
         DataTable dt = new DataTable();
         dt.Load(newStudent.ExecuteReader());
         conn.Close();
         dataGrid.DataContext = dt;
         MessageBox.Show(connectionStr);
```

I'm getting combobox for country value as comboBoxCountry.Text. but when I give that value in comboBoxDistrict selection changed method as listed on above I'm getting an empty combobox in districts.

How I'm supposed to populate both of them according to selection of first one.  any suggestions and code samples would be really grateful.
Thanks in advance.!

Comment: Can you verify if your query for districts is actually returning results?

If it does return results, check the databinding (direction) of your districts combobox. To update from source, or two-way.

Comment: @ISAF nope it doesn't return anything.

Comment: @ISAF thing is this comboBoxCountry.text string not identify by this method

Comment: While your problem is pretty understandable, I would suggest you to implement your application using an approach that separates the view and the data processing (e.g. MVVM). Building a correct model will solve all your issues.

Comment: @dymanoid  can you direct me for such a source then as I have mentioned I don't have knowledge on WPF development. Since I have to submit this today I don't have enough time on learning MVVM from the beginning. I appreciate your concern and definitely go for that. can you point out to me the problem in my code?

Comment: See: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23222778/bind-text-to-selected-item-in-combobox?rq=1) for combobox databinding. for databinding properties to the selected value. be sure to use the proper property (selected value, or selectedItem.text)

Small tutorial to start with MVVM: [Link](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/mvvm/mvvm_hooking_up_views.htm)

Comment: @ISAF thank you for your effort. Will give a shot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well i figured it out. actually its a silly mistake. I forgot to call comboBoxDistrict method in the countryselectionchange event method. Because of that mistake, district won't get updated. Also instead of comboBoxDistrict.Text use comboBoxDistrict.SelectedValue to get the selected value and use variable for that instead of doing

```
              string connectionStr = new_student_sql + comboBoxCountry.Text   + 
              "' AND District= '" + comboBoxDistrict.Text + "'";
```

use a varible,

```
              String country= comboBoxCountry.SelectedValue.ToString();
```

so that its easier to work with.
Thanks anyone who have tried to solve this and directred me to MVVM pattern and I would definitely give a shot.